# How to add many html buttons that use same javascript into loop results?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the following codes on my html page:

```
<input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="metin" placeholder="Geben Sie Artikel Nr" style="width: 30%;"/><br/><br/>
<input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="Suche (Advanced)" onclick="search()" /><br/><br/>
<div class="cevap" style="background-color:#e6e6e6; border: 0px solid green; padding: 2px; margin: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i></div>
```

and between `<head> ... </head>` :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      function search() {
         metin = $('input[name="metin"]').val();
         $.post('/wp-content/plugins/ajax-test/SearchByNumberNew.php', {yazi: metin}, function (gelen_cevap) {
            $('.cevap').html(gelen_cevap);
         });
      }
</script>
```

I am sending `yazi` into `SearchByNumberNew.php` and after some processes inside it I am getting the results into `<div class="cevap"...`

Until here it is okay. I am trying to put several buttons next to every result in the `<div>` that are sending the related value (`$parcano`)again into `SearchByNumberNew.php`. So I want to make a new search with the new value and refill the `<div>` with the new results (of course after deleting the previous results).

to do that I added following code into the loop in the `SearchByNumberNew.php`:

```
...
?><input type="hidden" name="metin" value="<?php echo $parcano;?>"/><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()" /><br/><br/>
   <?php
...
```

and following code between `<head> ... </head>` :

```
  function searchin() {
     metin = $('input[name="metin"]').val();
     $.post('/wp-content/plugins/ajax-test/SearchByNumberNew.php', {yazi2: metin}, function (gelen_cevap) {
        $('.cevap').html(gelen_cevap);
     });
  }
```

I tried many variations: yazi, yazi2, metin, metin2, etc..., unsetting the values before the loop, etc...

In the first search that I enter the value in the input box, it is always okay. I get a list of results with many buttons for each result line.

As far as I see in the button codes on the page, all of them have the correct values.

But when I click any of them, they always send the first buttons value into my php file.

What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate for your kind helps,

Regards,
Murat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the wrong identifier `$('input[name="metin"]').val();` will always return the value of the last input with name metin, try grouping each input group in a div and instead of:

`$('input[name="metin"]').val();`

use this if you want to use the input's value

`$(this).parent().find('input[name="metin"]').val();`

and this if you want to use the button's value

`$(this).val();`

The php code should look something like this:

```
...
?> 
<div>
   <input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()" /><br/><br/>
</div>
   <?php
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Mostafa Kasem, I applied what you adviced. So, now the buttons in the list do not send the first button's value of the list, but all of them send the very first value what I wrote in the input box.

Comment: I didn't see that you're using the value of the button, instead, the input's value was the one that's used, anyways I've edited my answer and added both codes if you want to use button's value or input's.

Comment: In the first search I use the text input box with manual text entry + search button, then I get a list with many buttons for each rows, then I click on the one of these buttons (there is no manual entry here, buttons are getting value from the list row), then this value should be searched as if it is entered in the text input box which is still on the top.

Comment: Then use the $(this).val(); solution for searchin function. I'm not sure why you're appending a new metin input though, I'm suggesting since it's not used you can completely delete it from the SearchByNumberNew page.

Comment: Hi @Mostafa Kasem, after your advices I have been playing around since 2 weeks (not all the days, but often), I am feeling that I am around the solution, but no success yet :( Last situation `...
<div>
   <input type="hidden" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="metin2" value="<?php echo $parcano;?>" /><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()" /><br/><br/>
</div>
...` and `metin2 = $(this).val();` don't trigger the javascript (see next comment pls)...

Comment: ... `...
<div>
   <input type="hidden" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="metin2" value="<?php echo $parcano;?>" /><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()" /><br/><br/>
</div>
...` and `metin2 = $(this).parent().find('input[name="metin2"]').val();` does trigger the javascript but doesn't send parameter to php file, as far as I see in network activity (by F12). Would you have a new advice? I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start your jQuery block?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     (function($) {
          function search() {
            var metin = $('input[name="metin"]').val();
             $.post('/wp-content/plugins/ajax-test/SearchByNumberNew.php', {yazi: metin}, function (gelen_cevap) {
                $('.cevap').html(gelen_cevap);
             });
          }
     })( jQuery );
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gaspar, but maybe I did not understand well: I think that my problem is in the `function searchin()`, not in the `function search()` , right?

Answer (score 0):

As far I see your code, no where I see you are using the value of button. Instead you are using value of a input box. If you use the value $('input[name="metin"]').val() then jquery will search for input box from top of the page and return you the first result it matches. So it will always bring the first result.

There are couple of ways to do solve your problem. You can pass this parameter in the button onClick event and as a button value you can give reference to the input you want to take the value from

```
<input type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" value="metin1" onclick="searchin(this)" />

  function searchin(param) {
     metin = $('input[name="+ param.val() + "]').val();
     $.post('/wp-content/plugins/ajax-test/SearchByNumberNew.php', {yazi2: metin}, function (gelen_cevap) {
        $('.cevap').html(gelen_cevap);
     });
  }
```

Or second way is bind a jquery event to a button.

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
     metin = $('input[name="+ this.val() + "]').val();
})
```

As far I understood your question. I think this way you can achieve your task. Otherwise let me know if have any queries.